# Creating dialogue boxes for editing and deleting records in Yii

Tags: php, jquery, yii

In My Web app I have a CRUD table and I need to implement a dialogue ox on clicking a particular record for editing ,deleting and making other changes. I googled it but unable to find proper tutorials.

Any body kindly help me how should I proceed. How should I implement it? I know its a silly question but unable to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend checking out the [x-editable](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/x-editable) extension for Yii, which will help you implement the features I believe you're looking for.

I find the [YiiBooster](http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/) extension very useful. It contains the same features as x-editable and much more.